# How to request for refresh token extension period for personal use of Youtube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api

I have a passion project where I'm using Raspberry Pi to perform headless automated operation of capturing timelapse photos, stitching all of them into a video and then upload it (as public video) to a specific Youtube channel via Youtube Data API once a day, every day (Might plan to last for a year, if possible).

I currently have the Youtube API credentials, but will plan to get the refresh token via https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground. But, from what I understand, the refresh token only last for 7 days due to the publishing status in testing mode, and the only way to remove the expiration date is by changing it to production and have the application verified.

However,

- As this is my passion project, my application that uses Youtube Data API is for personal use only, so I have no interest in sharing that API with other people, nor is publishing my application at all
- I have no interest in registering a website domain just to changing the publishing status to production and have my application verified
- My application running Raspberry Pi should not involve any human interaction, that includes constant manual re-authentication via browser (in events where refresh token expires after 7 days) for every request to upload a video to Youtube channel. (First time authentication is fine)

Is there a way that I could request for refresh token extension period for personal use of Youtube Data API? Thank you.